# Bitwise xor on float python

Tags: python, math, floating-point, bitwise-xor, lorawan

I'm goint to build a temperature measurement application in Python (on a resource constrained IoT device). I'm going to measure the temperature of a sensor, compare it with the previous measurement and only send the data to the server if the new measurement is within some allowed deviation. So:

1) Measure the temperature of a sensor

2) Check if the measurement deviates from the previous measurement by more than some set deviation

**Example**:

*Previous measurement was 24.0 C, allowed deviation 0,3 C*

1) Temperature measured to be 23,5 C

2) The measurement deviates by more than what is allowed. Send to server

My initial idea is to do a bitwise xor on the previous and the current measurement and thereafter subtract this from the allowed deviation.

If the result is positive -> data is not sent

If the result is negative -> send data

I'm struggling to do this in Python and would appreciate some help. Alternatively any suggestions on how to do this differently would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why does `if abs(current_temp - previous_temp) > max_deviation: send_to_server(current_temp)` not work?

Comment: Why bitwise XOR? What's wrong with `if abs(temp - old) >= 0.3: ...`?

Comment: Bitwise xor on floating point *representations* is generally meaningless.Bitwise xor on floating point *values* is not particularly useful because floating point values are often approximations.  There's a good reason it's not defined for any language.

Answer (score 0):

XOR is not defined for floating-point types. XOR is a Boolean operation, so it essentially operates on two bits and produces one bit. It is suitable for use on integers because there is a close association between the integer values and the bits used to represent them (each bit represents an assigned power of two, or is the sign bit). So a bitwise XOR operation performs an XOR on each individual bit position in two integers.

In floating-point, there is not a close association between the floating-point values and bits used to represent them. Some bits are for the exponent field, and XORing them would have strange effects on the represented value. Other bits are in the significand (fraction) field, but their value is dependent on the exponent field, and XORing the significand bits of two floating-point numbers with different exponents would also have weird effects.

To find the difference of two floating-point values, simply subtract one from the other (using a normal floating-point subtraction operation). If you merely want to know the magnitude of the difference, not its sign, take the absolute value of the result of the subtraction.